# Prettify parsed XML from Json on Client with Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xml, meteor

I have the following code:

```
Meteor.call('fetchData', uri, function(err, response) {
            var x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.content, null, 3));
            template.isOpenConfig.set(x);
            console.log(x);
        });
```

The output in the console is very well formatted but inside the DOM (template.set) it gets displayed minified.

Is there any trick?

The desired output of the displayed DOM should be like this:

```
<groot>
    <!-- Comments -->
    <something>600000</something>
    <!-- Comments -->
    <dropdown>
        <foobar>
            <foo>leomon</foo>
            <bar>rasperry</bar>
        </foobar>
        <foobar>
            <foo>orange</foo>
            <bar>cherry</bar>
        </foobar>
    </dropdown>
    <asd>1000</asd>
</groot>
```

I could use jQuery for this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So how does this look in the DOM, and how do you want it to look?

Comment: The string inside the DOM is minified, whilst it should have the output of the structure posted.

Comment: I'm guessing you have to replace newlines with `<br/>` or something. They're not the same in JavaScript as in HTML.

Comment: That's why I opened this question.

Comment: Are you trying to display the json directly on the page? Like in a textarea or something?